# How to parse json encoded html data to simple html in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I tried some of the examples but couldn't get it to work. I have a script that produces HTML results and those results are fetched by Ajax request. But the fetched results are escaped therefore not working as normal HTML.

**PHP (Just a small part)**

```
if($count > 0){
    echo json_encode(array('heading' => '<div id="found">Here is all!</div>', 'list' => $thelist));
}
else{
    echo json_encode(array('heading' => '<div id="empty_storage"><img src="icon.png"><br>Its lonely here!</div>', 'list' => $thelist));
}
```

**AJAX/ JQUERY**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    //$("#list").html('<div id="loader"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-fw fa-5x fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Waiting...</div>');
    setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "generate_list.php",
               dataType:"json",
               cache: false,
               success: function(result){
                     result = JSON.parse(result);
                     $("#list ul").html(result['list']);
               }
        });
    }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="list">
<ul>
</ul>
</div>
```

**ERROR IN CONSOLE**

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of
>   the JSON data

**UPDATE:**

Error removed but when I try to show the data in the html tags only one shows up.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    //$("#list").html('<div id="loader"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-fw fa-5x fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Waiting...</div>');
    setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "generate_list.php",
               dataType:"json",
               cache: false,
               success: function(result){
                     $("#list").html(result.heading);
                     $("#list ul").html(result.list);
               }
        });
    }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

**WHAT $thelist CONTAINS**

```
    $thelist .= '<li><span class="type">'.$extn.'</span><span class="link"><a href=./storage/'.$namehref.'>'.$name.'</a></span><span class="size">'.$size.'</span><span class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</li>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already added the

```
dataType:"json"
```

There will be no need to use

```
JSON.parse();
```

result in success is already formatted as JSON.

Also to use the `list` property of your JSON.

```
result.list

     $("#list ul").html(result.list);
```

Comment: ok why is it that when I fetch list and heading together then only one show up? Check the edited question.

Comment: Is your list an array?

Comment: You missed a paranthesis somewhere. Will this work for a set of html list? Wont it keep appending the whole set everytime the page is refreshed?

Comment: I thing a simple $(json.heading) will do here

Comment: In that case just `append(result.list)` or just `.html(result.list)`. I updated again.

Comment: Firstly using append(result.list) keeps appending the whole set again and again but the html one does the work of not repeating the same set. Secondly either or of the two gets displayed.

Comment: It seems to me that when we are adding the html element from the JS it removes the basic structure that I have created in the HTML file. Any views?